# Apache mod_rewrite - Priority not working?

Tags: mod-rewrite, dns, apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

my mind is freaking out. I dont find the error!
I just want that some subdomains:

CLOUD, BITWARDEN and NORMAL (e.g cloud.example.com, tresor.example.com and example.com)

:80 cloud -> :443 cloud (works)

**:80 bitwarden -> :443 normal (wrong)**

:443 bitwarden -> :443 bitwarden (works)

:80 normal -> :443 normal (works)

````
# CLOUD 
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
ServerName cloud.example.com
ServerAlias *.cloud.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/cloud.example.com/
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subexample2/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subexample2/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName cloud.example.com
ServerAlias *.cloud.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://cloud.example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cloud.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# BITWARDEN 
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
ServerName tresor.example.com
ServerAlias *.tresor.example.com
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
RequestHeader set X-Real-IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subexample2/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subexample2/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName tresor.example.com
ServerAlias *.tresor.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://tresor.example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =tresor.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# NORMALE  example
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subexample/
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subexample2/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subexample2/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found it out:

I deleted every :80 vhost and created one at the top of the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```